# Googlemap iframe not looking good in a display:none DIV and hide/show via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, iframe

I'm trying to add a google map to my website. It works like a charm if I keep the map always visible. The issue is that I want to hide/show it when users click on a button. In order to do that I created a div called #googlemap with display:none, then a few JS lines makes the DIV visible when I click on a button. The issue is that for some reason the map does not look OK at all with this solution (see pictures, looks like the address is not taken into consideration with the hide/show solution). I created a JSFiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/PwyLF/ Thanks for your help

Not OK:
[image: Not OK]

OK (if I remove display:none)
[image: OK]

CSS

```
.block {
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
    background: red;
}

#googlemap {
    width: 800px;
    height:600px;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="block"><a href="#" id='link'>Click here to show map</a></div>

<div id="googlemap">
     <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2624.9983685732213!2d2.29432085!3d48.85824149999999!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d%3A0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!2sgoogle+map+paris+eiffel+tower!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sbe!4v1387990714927" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $('#googlemap').hide();
 })

 $('.block').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });

$('#link').click(function(e) {
 $('#googlemap').toggle();
 window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?
**http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/T7jLf/20/**

```
$(".button").on("click", function () {
$("#googlemap").slideToggle("slow");
$(this).text($(this).text() == "Hide map" ? "Show map" : "Hide map");
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing, looks like in your example the map is showed by default. How do you hide it by default? (until users click on the button) Many thanks

Comment: give css display:none and if its not fitting properly you have to quit iframe and use the google v3 api. Also if you feel the answer given is right tick it right for other users.

Comment: this should be able to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311874/google-map-position-incorrect-on-load

Comment: Thanks... I'll take your offer. I tried to use api v3 but exactly the same issue if the div container has display:none. So I had a look at your link and the workaround with the DIV not hidden but -10000px to the left seems to be the solution. Unfortunately I have no idea how to integrate that with you show/hide button (ie. would be -10000 to the left when the page loads, back to normal when users click on "show map", then back to -100000 left when users click on "hide map". Many thanks for your help!