# Google map iframe and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, iframe

Can anyone give me a example on how to format this. I am not familiar with Jquery and what I have tried does not work. I don't have the rep to add to the thread and ask. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a iframe google map in tabs that are not loading correctly very similar to this problem;

From a post [Google map position incorrect on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311874/google-map-position-incorrect-on-load)

"The problem is that the place you want the map to center on ends up in the top left corner of the iframe for some reason. I think it's because on google's side the map resize event is firing too early before it knows the full size of the iFrame.

Remove the iframe src tag.

Embed the below javascript code somewhere below the iframe:

```
jQuery("iframe#headerMap").attr("src", "http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?etc etc....");
```

Because it loads the map after the iframe is there. If I still have problems in the future I'll try adding a short delay to the above code, making it run after document load."

Comment: Why would you want to load google maps in an iframe? Just include the maps js API in your header and use your target DIV as container when you instantiate the google.maps.Map object.

Comment: In have a lot of maps to load and the API was very slow to load. These  load easily but don't do well when hidden (offset/zoomed out). I was hoping that dealing with the tab problem would be easier to work around then a slow API load. If i could find out how to format the jQuery example so that it worked that would get me there at least closer.